# TypeError: el.inputmask._valueGet is not a function maskScope@http://localhost:4200

Tags: angular, input-mask

I am using `Inputmask` package in angular 2.0. I added one date field with mask. When I open that page first time. then no error occur and it is working fine.

But when i re-visit the page then it show me following error:

> ERROR
>   Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: `el.inputmask._valueGet` is not a function maskScope@http://localhost:4200/0.chunk.js:1391:91

```
import Inputmask from "inputmask"; 

@Component({
   template: `
     <input type="text" [formControl]="member_since" data-inputmask="'alias':'date'">
   `
})
...
ngOnInit() { 
  Inputmask().mask(document.querySelectorAll("input")); 
}
```

Comment: Please include your relevant code.

Comment: In Component 

import Inputmask from "inputmask";

ngOnInit() {
  Inputmask().mask(document.querySelectorAll("input"));
}

in view page

<input type="text" class="form-control" [formControl]="member_since" data-inputmask="'alias':'date'" >

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `ngAfterViewInit` life-cycle hook, and not the `ngOnInit`. After the view initializes, you can be sure that all elements exists:

```
ngAfterViewInit() { 
    Inputmask().mask(document.querySelectorAll("input")); 
}
```

This is obviously not the advised way to do it, using `querySelectorAll`. This way it's selecting all `input` elements inside your entire document. Better would be to create a template ref variable, and import this in your component using `ViewChild`.

```
@Component({
    template: `<input type="text" data-inputmask="'alias':'date'" #inputDate>`
})
export class InputDateComponent {

    @ViewChild('inputDate')
    public inputDate: ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit() { 
        Inputmask().mask(this.inputDate.nativeElement); 
    }

}
```

Even better would be to create a directive, but I'll leave that up to you to figure that one out